# libtool directory argument does not work

Tags: bash, unix, qemu, libtool

In qemu I use below command to install tools such as `qemu-ga.exe`,
but the problem is `libtool` does not accept its directory argument correctly.

If I run the command like this,

```
msdperera@msdperera-PC MSYS /qemu
$ libtool --quiet --mode=install install -c -m 0755 qemu-ga.exe qemu-img.exe qemu-io.exe  "/c:/Program Files/QEMU"
install: target 'Files/QEMU/qemu-ga.exe' is not a directory
```

what is the correct format for the directory argument?

Comment: I would backquote the space in the filename: `"/c:/Program\ Files/QEMU"`

Comment: @tgo I tried that, it still didn't work.